# What are the pros and cons of having one lambda function with "smaller functions" vs multiple functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function with 10 "smaller functions" inside that single lambda which gets accessed by 10 api gateway endpoints.

What are the pros and cons of designing the backend this way? 
I know it's more difficult to manage all those functions when testing, but how would it compare speedwise to 10 seperate lambda functions?

```
exports.handler =  (event) => {

    const path = event.path;
    const method = event.httpMethod;

    if(path === '/getmail' && method === 'GET'){
        return mailQuery(event);
    }

   if(path === '/getmessagethread' && method === 'GET'){
        return getMessageThread(event);
    }

   if(path === '/replytomessage' && method === 'POST'){
        return replyToMessage(event);
    }

    if(path === '/sendmessage' && method === 'POST'){
        return sendMessage(event);
    }

    . . .
};
```

Comment: **primarily opinion-based** Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

imo do whatever you feel comfortable with and that works best for the use case. Here is just my 2 cents on the subject though:

**Pros**:

- Only need to manage one function and it's code
- This might be easier to test then using [SAM Local](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli) as we could have multiple event objects to test with

**Cons**:

- If multiple requests come in that function's reserved concurrency(if it has that) could be exhausted since it is only that one function serving all those requests
- API Gateway's max timeout is 30 seconds, so if this function executes longer due to this extra code then the request will fail
- Could also increase the deployment package size which Lambda has the following limit
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

  > 50 MB (zipped, for direct upload)
  >   250 MB (unzipped, including layers)
  >   3 MB (console editor)

Speedwise I don't think it would make much difference. I don't believe there would be much difference in the time to execute if a function was called as opposed to having the code directly in the handler function.

HTH

-James

Comment: The question asks for opinion and you are giving opinion but opinions are off topic on SO. Such questions should be voted to be closed. Not all questions can or should be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: should I remove my answer?